# При инициализации есть нуль-терминатор?

Tags: c++, c

Я создаю динамический массив таким образом `wchar_t* tempString = new wchar_t[20];`. Есть ли шанс, что среди его элементов окажется '\0'? По сути это же просто ноль и он вполне мог случайно поместиться в какой-то элемент этого массива или его там гарантированно не будет?

Comment: то, что ноль там окажется, шанс есть. То, что ноля там гарантированно не будет - никто обещать не может. Но лучше считать, что нуля там нет и явно инициализировать свои переменные.

Comment: всё зависит от операционной системы и её реализации выделения памяти и защиты. Ответ точно нет или точно да или не определено.

Comment: Неинициализированные объекты хранят [indeterminate value](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.indet#def:value,indeterminate). Попытка чтения такого значения приводит (за исключением нескольких очень специфичных случаев) к неопределённому поведению. Результат чтения значения из неинициализированного массива  `tempString` непредсказуем. Прочитаться может как ноль, так и не ноль, или программа может аварийно завершиться, или может наблюдаться какое-то иное контринтуитивное поведение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что ноль там окажется, шанс есть. То, что ноля там гарантированно не будет - никто обещать не может. Но лучше считать, что нуля там нет и явно инициализировать свои переменные.

Но я тут чуточку подумал, и берусь утверждать, что `'\0'` там как раз нет. Дело в том, что строка то в примере - wchar_t*, то есть, в ней находятся широкие символы. А `'\0'` - это обычный char. Поэтому, лучше говорить о `L'\0'` который имеет подходящий тип. Но это такое.

Если копнуть шире, то очень часто в отладочном сборке менеджер памяти может делать разные тесты - например, заполнить нулями или каким-либо шаблоном (студийный компилятор выделенную память [может заполнить шаблоном 0xcd 0xcd 0xcd 0xcd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2022)) и в этом случае там точно не будет нулей.